# Why is this test unit pass?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, nunit

I spend over 2 hours on this... i can't figure out why this test is PASSING. I mean.. it shouldnt return the view "Completed" but in the test it does! It say Expected "string.Empty" but returned "Completed" however for the creditcard to pass.. the securitycode need to be "test" which is isnt at all in the test. So it should return the default view (which is like view();).

What i am doing wrong ? it is my test that is wrong ? or the controller logic ?

Thanks a lots.

---

```
[Test]
public void Cannot_Check_Out_If_Credit_Card_Failed_To_Process()
{
 var mockOrderSubmitter = new Mock<IOrderSubmitter>();
 var mockCreditCardProcessor = new Mock<ICreditCardProcessor>();

// Arrange: Given a user has a non-empty cart
var cart = new Cart();
cart.AddItem(new Product(), 1);

// Arrange: ... but the credit card failed to process
var cartController = new CartController(null, mockOrderSubmitter.Object, mockCreditCardProcessor.Object);
var result = cartController.CheckOut(cart, new ShippingDetails(), new CreditCard() { SecurityCode = "123" });

// Assert
result.ShouldBeDefaultView();
}
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckOut(Cart cart, ShippingDetails shippingDetails, CreditCard creditCard)
{
// Empty carts can't be checked out
if (cart.Lines.Count == 0)
    ModelState.AddModelError("Cart", "Sorry, your cart is empty!");

// Everything is valid
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Effectue le paiement.
    TransactionResult result = creditcardProcessor.TakePayment(creditCard, cart.ComputeTotalValue());
    if (result == TransactionResult.Success)
    {
        // Envoi la commande
        orderSubmitter.SubmitOrder(cart, shippingDetails);
        cart.Clear();
        return View("Completed");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("CreditCard", "Sorry, we couldn't process your credit card, please verify your credit card details and retry.");
        return View(new CheckOutViewModel());
    }

}
else // Something was invalid
    return View(new CheckOutViewModel());
}
```

---

```
public class MainCreditCardProcessor : ICreditCardProcessor
{
    public TransactionResult TakePayment(CreditCard card, decimal amount)
    {
        if (card.SecurityCode == "test")
            return TransactionResult.Success;
        else
            return TransactionResult.TransactionDeclined;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Well there is an instance of MainCreditCardProcessor and EmailOrderSubmitter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this test unit pass ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686814/why-is-this-test-unit-pass)

Comment: ops sorry i though posting this question wasnt worked, so i reposted it. You are correct this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to this. The mocks object doesnt have any implementation. (Which i should have know before that)